Error Reading Characters of String During Debugging: Unable to Read Memory in Visual Studio
I'm learning C++ on visual studio 2022 and encountering an error while using breakpoint and debugging.
When I step into a function that takes a const char* parameter, I receive the following error message: "Error reading characters of string: Unable to read memory.
I divided the project in 3 different files Log.h , Log.cpp & main.cpp
There code are as follows respectively:
#pragma once

void Log(const char* message);

#include "Log.h"
#include <iostream>

void Log(const char* message)
{
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
}

#include <iostream>
#include "Log.h"

int main()
{
    Log("Hello World!"); // Breakpoint on this line
    std::cin.get();
}

When I run this through local Windows Debugger and 'Step Into' Log function it takes me from main.cpp to log.cpp but when I move my cursor over 'Message' variable it shows "Error reading characters of string" & "Unable to read memory"
Verified String Validity: Ensured that "Hello World!" is a valid string literal, which should be accessible throughout the program execution.
Compiler Settings: Disabled optimizations in the project settings to ensure accurate debugging.
Optimization: Disabled (/Od)
Memory Checks: Looked for any memory corruption or mismanagement in the surrounding code, but the issue persists.

Step once more, so that you are positioned on the first line of the function body rather than on the line with function name and parameters. Parameters simply haven't been initialized yet.
